# How can I comment to questions when I don't have enough reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, comments, flags

I came across a question for which I have the correct answer. But since the question is a duplicate and the answer only requires a link to that question, the best way to provide the link would be in comments. Since I don't have enough reputation to flag it as a duplicate nor to comment, what can I do?

Comment: I am talking about askubuntu.

Comment: @sushilthe once you get 200 on any 1 site, the association bonus will give you enough to flag and comment on any site you have an account

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get reputation. That's all there is really. You'll need [15 to flag or 50 to comment](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) on AskUbuntu. Especially for the flagging that would require next to no effort. So, get to work. ;)

Comment: It's kind of a loop. One way to gain reputation is to answer and to answer we need reputations.

Comment: You don't need rep to answer regular questions. You only need to have earned 10 rep on the site to answer protected questions.